# dbContext.SaveChanges() not saving and not outputting an error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio

Im trying to update a User-object in my MVC-project, but it doesn't seem to save the new values that I input.

Can anyone spot where I am doing something wrong?

This is the method where I do the saving, I know I get all the way down to `db.SaveChanges();` by running my `Debug.WriteLines()`.

```
public bool editUser(string email, User innUser)
{
    var db = new PastaContext();
    try
    {
        User editUser = db.Users.Find(email);
        editUser.Firstname = innUser.Firstname;
        Debug.WriteLine(innUser.Firstname);
        Debug.WriteLine(editUser.Firstname);
        editUser.Surname = innUser.Surname;
        editUser.Address = innUser.Address;
        editUser.Phonenr = innUser.Phonenr;
        var newUser = new dbUser();
        byte[] passwordDb = createHash(innUser.Password);
        newUser.Password = passwordDb;
        newUser.Email = email;


        if (editUser.Postcode != innUser.Postcode)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Inside in Postcode");
            // Postcode is altered.  First check if the new postcode is in the tabel already
            City existingCity = db.Cities.Find(innUser.Postcode);
            if (existingCity == null)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Inside in not exsisting postcode");
                // poststedet eksisterer ikke, må legges inn
                var newCity = new City()
                {
                    Postcode = innUser.Postcode,
                    Cityname = innUser.city.Cityname
                };
                db.Cities.Add(newCity);
            }
            else
            {   // city with the new postcode already exists, changing only postcode of user
                editUser.Postcode = innUser.Postcode;
                Debug.WriteLine("Inside in exsisting postcode");
            }
        };
        Debug.WriteLine("Right before save");
        db.SaveChanges();
        Debug.WriteLine("Returning true");
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("returning false");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Output of catching the exception:

```
System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException: Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()
at Oblig1.DBUser.editUser(String email, User innUser) in c:\Users\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX\DBUser.cs:line 55
```

Output of the errors:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll
Entity of type "City" in state "Added" has the following validation errors:
- Property: "Postcode", Error: "Postcode must be added"
Entity of type "User_546F9926F8DC53E2EF66BA48BE431DF1B26DEBEFA54B0597E60AEB1839DD022C" in state "Modified" has the following validation errors:
- Property: "city", Error: "The city field is required."
```

The model i am using with three tables:

```
public class User
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Firstname must be added")]
    public string Firstname { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Surname must be added")]
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Address must be added")]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public string Postcode { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "E-mail must be added")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Phonenr must be added")]
    public string Phonenr { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password must be added")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual City city { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class dbUser
{
    [Key]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public byte[] Password { get; set; }
}

public class City
{
    [Key]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Postcode must be added")]
    public string Postcode { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "City must be added")]
    public string Cityname { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: what does your debug output look like?

Comment: Of course! Just give me a sec.

Comment: Look like you're getting a DbEntityValidationException. Catch the exception and it will tell you what you need to know (EntityValidationErrors property).

Comment: Are you sure that your connection is open?!

Comment: @MattyM updated with the output from the exception now!

Comment: @adamNature Not enough, you need to read the `EntityValidationErrors` collection.

Comment: @adamNature As DavidG stated, you need to read the EntityValidationErrors collection. You can loop through them and output each one.

Comment: I think that `System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException` counts as outputting an error

Comment: in visual studio, you can go to debug/exceptions, and click the checkbox under `Thrown` and `Common language runtime exceptions`, and this will make a breakpoint when the exception gets thrown.  At this point, when you run into the exception, go to the locals window, and somewhere in the exception object will be some more detils on your entity validation errors.  That should tell you what your problem is

Comment: @SamIam Reading `EntityValidationErrors` in debug environment is notoriously annoying to do unfortunately. You can get round it by putting this in your watch window though: `((System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException)ex).EntityValidationErrors`

Comment: @DavidG Added the output of the errors now.

Comment: Added the models aswell!

Comment: @DavidG Added the models now. I have two postcode, one in user and one in city. When i am updating the user (in the view) i am updating user.city.Postcode. Not user.Postcode.

Comment: @adamNature Is the incoming postcode empty?

Comment: @DavidG That was it! You're assumptions were correct, the innuser.postcode was empty. I changed it to innuser.city.postcode and it worked! Thanks for the help and for teaching me a thing or two about properly outputing the errors i recieve. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create your new city object you do this:

```
var newCity = new City()
{
    Postcode = innUser.Postcode,
    Cityname = innUser.city.Cityname
};
```

Instead you need to set the postcode using the `City.Postcode` property like this:

```
var newCity = new City()
{
    Postcode = innUser.city.Postcode,
    Cityname = innUser.city.Cityname
};
```